# Issue to write unit test for below method xUnit MOQ or NSubsitute c#

Tags: c#, .net, moq, xunit, nsubstitute

I'm facing issue while implementing unit test in xUnit using Moq and NSubstitue to a method in which two methods being called in same line.

```
public class Class1{

    private TestClient _client;

    public Class1(TestClient client){
    _client = client;
    }
    //method to write test
    public string GetData(){
    var response = _client.GetClient().GetSomeData("user");
    return response;
    }
 }
```

I tried to implement unit test as below:

```
[Fact]
public void TestGetData()
{
 //Arrange
 var input = "user";
 var exceptedResponse = "Succeess";
 
 //Act
 TestClient moqClient =  new Mock<TestClient>();
 moqClient.Setup(x => x.GetClient().GetSomeData().Returns("Succeess"));
 var result = new Class1().GetData();
 
 //Assert
 Assert.Equal(exceptedResponse, result);
}
```

But I'm getting exception as below while running the test at Setup line.

> Message:  System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: ...
> => ....Returns("Succeess", new[] {  }) Extension methods (here: SubstituteExtensions.Returns) may not be used in setup /
> verification expressions.
>
> Stack Trace:  Guard.IsOverridable(MethodInfo method, Expression
> expression) line 87
> ExpressionExtensions.g__Split|5_0(Expression e, Expression& r,
> MethodExpectation& p, Boolean assignment, Boolean
> allowNonOverridableLastProperty) line 234
> ExpressionExtensions.Split(LambdaExpression expression, Boolean
> allowNonOverridableLastProperty) line 149
> Mock.SetupRecursive[TSetup](Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression,
> Func`4 setupLast, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) line 643 Mock.Setup(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Condition condition) line 498 Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression`1
> expression) line 452

Please help how we can implement mocking for this using Moq or NSubsitute.

Thanks.

Comment: Is Class1 a test class or not? please note that in a clean design test code should be completely separated from production (none test code)

Comment: @Siraf, the code written above is sample production code. I want to write unit test for the class using Moq or NSubsitute frameworks. I'm facing issue in mocking this "_client.GetClient().GetSomeData("user");" line of code.

Comment: what issue are you facing? did you try something with Moq? if yes please share the code

Comment: Hey @Siraf, edited my question with test I implemented. But I'm getting error when setting up the mock result. Please check the question once and help me if you have any idea on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here the real issue is that `GetClient` method returns a certain type, and the `GetSomeData` method is defined on that type.

So let's assume TestClient.GetClient returns `IClient` (arbitrary type, as the question does not provide the type). You can create a `Mock<IClient>` and mock the `GetSomeData` method. And then you should mock the GetClient method (if possible) to return `mockClient.Object` so that the mocked return value can be retrieved.

Hope it helps,